# Как пристыковать две переменные но так чтобы при распечатывании они были одна под другой?

Tags: php

Есть две переменные содержащие строку.
$title содержит заголовок;
$text содержит текст.

пробовал так `$title.'<br>'.$text`
пристыковывать из и между ставить `<br>` но это не то. А так `$title.\n.$text` ошибку

Использование br не подходит если я хочу поместить эти переменные в `textarea` которые не воспринимает теги. В общем задача состоит в том чтобы текст переносился по строкам, но без использования тегов. Да много других еще вариантов где мне нужно чтобы текст переносился но никаких тегов не было, тот же кросспост куда уходит чиста строка текста, с переносами и прочим, но без тегов.
Например вот здесь текст переносится по строкам, но при этом никаких тегов нет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `$title."\n".$text`

Comment: так и вывелось: Заголовок\nОписание

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [PHP_EOL](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.constants.php), вот таким образом

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="45"><?php echo $title.PHP_EOL.$text ?></textarea>
```

Comment: спасибо, то что надо

Answer (score 0):

`nl2br()` дружит с `textarea`:

```
<?=nl2br("$title\n$text");?>
```

Comment: А что за символы перед скобкой?

Comment: Строковая функция php. 
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.nl2br.php